# Is SQL Server Authentication reasonably secure?

Tags: sql-server

I am a little hazy on how SQL Server Authentication works. My understanding is it scrambles, but does not encrypt, the password and then relies on TLS to send the password to the server. Presumably, with only SQL Server's self-signed certificate on the server, this could be subject to a man in the middle (MITM) attack. The following suggests that if there is a CA certificate on the server it will be used for SQL Server Authentication.

[SQL Server will use a certificate from a trusted certification authority if available for encrypting login packets.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16#sql-server-generated-self-signed-certificates)

ie Can I assume, that as long as there is a CA certificate on the server, SQL Server Authentication is reasonably secure?

Comment: Then pay for a certificate, if you are concerned, that much doesn't it cost.

Comment: I am asking if the use of the CA certificate is guaranteed, for SQL Server Authentication, if available.

Comment: As statedbon you liink clearly ,  if you don't have a trustworthy  certificate SQL server will generate one and use this. For me it isn't clear , have you a on nemesis server or aone in the internet ?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use active directory?

Comment: The link I posted is in the middle of an article on encrypted connections so it is not entirely clear if it relates to SQL Server Authentication. Has anyone here used something like Wireshark to see what actually happens?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to use AD from Linux and I have no intention of wading through treacle with our network group for a few days trying to resolve Kerberos double-hop problems etc on Windows clients.